# localhost redirected you too many times using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, mod-rewrite

```
if( isset($_COOKIE['user']) && !empty($_COOKIE['user']) ){
    header("Location: ./");
}
```

This is my code for login page. What I want to achieve is whenever someone is logged in [if a cookie named `user` exists], the user should be redirected to the homepage. I am using mod_rewrite to write URLs.

The problem I am facing is that whenever the cookie exists, and I go to `localhost/project/login/`, it shows ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:

[image: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS]

However when I use `localhost/project/login.php` it works fine.

Comment: if you downvote ... please let me know the reason ... I am trying to learn here ... and I have also went through stackoverflow and google.

Comment: is the homepage also doing a redirect back to login at all?

Comment: @nealio82  : when i click on log in button from the homepage, and if cookie exists, it redirects back to login page... works well !!

Comment: "it redirects back to **login page**... works well" - although at the top of your question you said "the user should be redirected to the **homepage**". - Which should it be? The login page or the homepage? What is the URL when you click on the login button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> header("Location: ./");
> ```

`./` is a *relative URL*. Consequently if you send back `Location: ./` in the HTTP response then the *browser* will interpret this as relative to whatever is currently displayed in the browser.

So...

When requesting `localhost/project/login/` (note the trailing slash), the browser will redirect back to `localhost/project/login/` (the same URL - *redirect loop*).

When requesting `localhost/project/login.php`, the browser will redirect to `localhost/project/` (your home page I assume).

To always redirect back to the homepage (`/project/`) from any URL-path depth then you would need to at least specify a root-relative URL in the `Location` header. For example:

```
header('Location: /project/');
```

(Or, you mess around calculating the current path depth from the request in order to construct a relative URL-path. But if you are going to do that then you might as well calculate the absolute URL of the homepage - or have this stored - which is arguably preferable.)